# war does not support nested "fileset" element

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant, build.xml

I am trying to run the build.xml file from eclipse for automating the process of creating the war and deploying it to server's webapps folder. I wrote a script for that but I got an error while running it that "war does not support nested "fileset" element".

I searched a lot on google but could not be able to find solution for this. Please help anybody. I'm using Ant version 1.9.7. Thanks in advance.

```
<target name="warTarget">
   <war warfile="myjar.war" needxmlfile="false">
     <filset dir="WebContent"></filset>
    </war>
    <antcall target="deployTarget"></antcall>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got `fileset` wrongly spelled

```
<filset dir="WebContent"></filset>
```

it should be

```
<fileset dir="WebContent"/>
```

For more on how to create war using WAR Task [Please see](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html)

Hope this helps